# How to do time calculations in excel without indicating the dates when end time is at the morning but start time is at the evening?

Tags: vba, excel

What I plan to do for my spreadsheet is (End Time) - (Start Time), however, the problem is that there are times where the employee finishes past midnight which may destroy the calculation (e.g. 2am - 10pm = a negative number). It is very tedious to write down the date for each cell and this would not be practical in our case. Also this leads to a higher occurrence of human error where if one forgets to put the date, it will return a wrong value.

To further paint my situation. I have 2 worksheets: one indicating the Production Start Time and Production End Time and the second one indicating Set-Up Start Time and Set-Up End Time. There can be many rows of set-up for every one row of production. Therefore, if the date values are wrong, then the values will vary significantly. (e.g. 12pm can be translated to 0.5 numerically, but 1/1/2017 12pm can be numerically valued at around 40,000. If calculations were performed it will be very wrong). Basically, all 4 time values for Production and Set-up times must be consistent for calculation.

Below is the VBA code of what calculations I am going to perform. For any of those who would find it useful.

```
Total_rows_NHI = Worksheets("Non-hourly Input").Range("A" & Rows.count).End(xlUp).Row
Total_rows_Set = Worksheets("Set-up Input").Range("A" & Rows.count).End(xlUp).Row
ReDim u4(2 To Total_rows_NHI) As Long
ReDim Case1(2 To Total_rows_NHI) As Long
ReDim Case2(2 To Total_rows_NHI) As Long
ReDim Case3(2 To Total_rows_NHI) As Long
ReDim Case4(2 To Total_rows_NHI) As Long

For k4 = 2 To Total_rows_NHI
    For g4 = 2 To Total_rows_Set
        Setup_Start = Worksheets("Set-up Input").Cells(g4, 5)
        Setup_End = Worksheets("Set-up Input").Cells(g4, 6)
        Prod_Start = Worksheets("Non-hourly Input").Cells(k4, 7)
        Prod_End = Worksheets("Non-hourly Input").Cells(k4, 8)
        Start_Quant = Worksheets("Non-hourly Input").Cells(k4, 9)
        End_Quant = Worksheets("Non-hourly Input").Cells(k4, 10)
        If Worksheets("Non-hourly Input").Cells(k4, 1) = Worksheets("Set-up Input").Cells(g4, 1) _
        And Worksheets("Non-hourly Input").Cells(k4, 2) = Worksheets("Set-up Input").Cells(g4, 2) _
        And Worksheets("Non-hourly Input").Cells(k4, 4) = Worksheets("Set-up Input").Cells(g4, 3) _
        And Worksheets("Non-hourly Input").Cells(k4, 5) = Worksheets("Set-up Input").Cells(g4, 4) Then
            u4(k4) = u4(k4) + (Setup_End - Setup_Start) * 24
            If Setup_Start < Prod_Start And Setup_Start < Prod_End And Setup_End > Prod_Start And Setup_End < Prod_End Then
                Case1(k4) = Case1(k4) + (Setup_End - Prod_Start) * 24
            End If
            If Setup_Start > Prod_Start And Setup_Start < Prod_End And Setup_End > Prod_Start And Setup_End > Prod_End Then
                Case2(k4) = Case2(k4) + (Prod_End - Setup_Start) * 24
            End If
            If Setup_Start > Prod_Start And Setup_Start < Prod_End And Setup_End > Prod_Start And Setup_End < Prod_End Then
                Case3(k4) = Case3(k4) + (Setup_End - Setup_Start) * 24
            End If
            If Setup_Start < Prod_Start And Setup_Start < Prod_End And Setup_End > Prod_Start And Setup_End > Prod_End Then
                Case4(k4) = Case4(k4) + (Prod_End - Prod_Start) * 24
            End If
        End If
    Next g4
Next k4

For k4 = 2 To Total_rows_NHI
    Start_Quant = Worksheets("Non-hourly Input").Cells(k4, 9)
    End_Quant = Worksheets("Non-hourly Input").Cells(k4, 10)
    Prod_Start = Worksheets("Non-hourly Input").Cells(k4, 7)
    Prod_End = Worksheets("Non-hourly Input").Cells(k4, 8)
    Worksheets("Non-hourly Input").Cells(k4, 12) = u4(k4)
    Worksheets("Non-hourly Input").Cells(k4, 13) = Case1(k4) + Case2(k4) + Case3(k4) + Case4(k4)
    Worksheets("Non-hourly Input").Cells(k4, 11) = (End_Quant - Start_Quant) / ((Prod_End - Prod_Start) * 24 - (Case1(k4) + Case2(k4) + Case3(k4) + Case4(k4)))
Next k4
```

Comment: (End Time) - (Start Time) + ((End Time) < (Start Time))

Comment: Thanks this works too. Do you know how to incorporate this in VBA logical operations?

Comment: Are you honestly asking me to document how to subtract one number from another?

Comment: I mean it doesn't seem to be the same in this case: `If Setup_Start > Prod_Start And Setup_Start < Prod_End And Setup_End > Prod_Start And Setup_End < Prod_End Then'. Anyway I think I can work from the answers here. Sorry for that. Time and date calculations for production metrics is a new problem to figure out for me

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
=MOD(EndTime-StartTime,1)
```

This will transform a (wrong) negative number to the right positive one.

Comment: Thanks this works. Although i'm not quite sure how to incorporate it to my VBA code's calculations. Especially with logical operations (e.g. Setup_Start > Prod_Start)

Comment: Sorry I thought you want to have a function for the worksheet